# How to put a listview inside a tab activity?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm a beginner in Android programming. I'm trying to make an application that shows a listview with different valors that depend on which tab i pressed. The problem I'm having is to put a Listview inside a tabhost and call it from the code. Anyone can explain me how to do it? I've searched in the web but the examples doesnt answer me totally.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont want to put list view in tabHost. Instead of that do this.

**Main Activity** - Where you implement the tabHost. Here you can create tabs and link it to specific activity.

**FirstTabActivity** - Implement your code here with your `ListView` as like normal activity.

**SecondTabActivity** - Implement your code here with your `ListView` as like normal activity.

**ThirdTabActivity** - Implement your code here with your `ListView` as like normal activity.

And So On.

**EDIT**

**Tutorial** - [See Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/).

Comment: So you said that I need to implement an activity which own XML right? But what I can't understand is this: how can i show the activity under the tabs? 
I don't have an example sorry :(

Comment: Yes. See the tutorial for more detail. It will answer for your comment.

Comment: Thank you. The strange thing is that I have MyKong in my bookmarks but I haven't read there!